# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase

## E/flutter ( 7704): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

```
> E/flutter ( 7704): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
> E/flutter ( 7704): <asynchronous suspension>
> E/flutter ( 7704): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
> E/flutter ( 7704): <asynchronous suspension>
> E/flutter ( 7704): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
> E/flutter ( 7704): <asynchronous suspension>
> E/flutter ( 7704): #3      main (package:vendorapp/main.dart:6:3)
> E/flutter ( 7704): <asynchronous suspension>
> E/flutter ( 7704):
```

## app\build.gradle:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

## project\build.gradle:

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
> repositories {
> google()
> mavenCentral()
> }
>
> dependencies {
> classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
> }
> }
>
> allprojects {
> repositories {
> google()
> mavenCentral()
> }

## I already added all the required snippets in the gradle files

Comment: Check your firebase configuration.